# Dynamic EventKey not working React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

I am dynamically rendering my tabs in React-Bootstrap, but somehow the `eventKey` doesn't recognise the values and the tabs aren't clickable.
Here's the code.

```
var tabButtons = tabsList.map(function(text, index){
                        if(text.enabled==1)
                        { 
                        return <NavItem eventKey={index} key={index}><center> {text.value}</center></NavItem>; }
                      });
```

Here `tabList` is an array which contains information about whether the button is enabled. If yes, then display the button information.

The code where I am calling these tabs.

```
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Tab.Container id="tab" defaultActiveKey="0">
                <Row className="show-grid">
                  <Col sm={12}>
                    <Nav bsStyle="tabs" justified>
                      {tabButtons}
                    </Nav>
                  </Col>

                  <Col sm={12}>
                    <Tab.Content animation>
                      <Tab.Pane eventKey="0">
                       <FirstTabContent />
                      </Tab.Pane>
                      <Tab.Pane eventKey="1">
                       Second
                      </Tab.Pane>
                      <Tab.Pane eventKey="2">
                         <ThirdTabContent />
                      </Tab.Pane>


                    </Tab.Content>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
                </Tab.Container>
            </div>
            );
```

I have no idea, why aren't the `eventKey` able to use the `index` values.
Anything I am missing? Another approach perhaps?

Comment: button are rendering properly ??

Comment: Yes, they are rendered correctly. When I click on them, they do not trigger any response, so that made me circle out the `eventKey` thingy. Might be something else too :|

Answer (score 1):

Apparently after some hit and tries, got it working.

The problem was indeed in `eventKey`.

Replaced `eventKey="0"` with `eventKey={0}`

Though I have no idea what difference it makes. Anyone?

Comment: One returns a string with zero inside, the other returns the number zero. Same thing happens if you want a true prop, something="true" will not work as expected unless you fix it to something={true}. The brackets just tell it "it's a javascript value" instead of a static string.